# How to add custom glsl transition file in ffmpeg command ? Getting error like when adding glsl file is "No such filter: 'gltransition"

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, fluent-ffmpeg

I was tried with using command

> ffmpeg -i hiking.mp4 -i video2.mp4 -filter_complex "gltransition=duration=4:offset=1.5:source=crosswarp.glsl" -y outputFile.mp4

After running this command getting error like
[ERROR MESSAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WcIQp.png)

> No such filter: 'gltransition'

I found the way to add transitions using ffmpeg-concat library but in this way can add inbuilt transition names but in my case need to add custom transition glsl file in ffmpeg command

How to overcome from this error in windows system?